# Query information inside the files(UNIX,AWK)

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I need to query the information of about 1000 files in once.
For example
My filename is

```
Test_001_20150517
Test_001_20150530
```

Information inside the file

```
{
1=2015
2=8
3=4
4=98888
5=123456
}
{
1=2014
2=456
3=5588
4=95858
5=67889
}
```

I want to query these 2 files with the conditions that 1=2015 and only show the result of 5

```
cat *201505*|awk -F '=' '{if ($1=="5"){print $2}}'
```

I'm trying to show the result but there is no condition that 1=2015 I don't know what should I do because 1 and 5 is the same as $1.

Sorry for my poor English if there is something wrong or misunderstand in my question.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: Is that the literal file contents? Consistently? One `key=value` pair per-line with `{` and `}` on their own lines?

Comment: @PowerBoom, In the file, there are blocks delimited by { and }, a field to the left of = and a field to the right of it. How do you think should the query be formed in terms of these elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
$ awk -F'=' '{a[$1]=$2} /}/ && (a[1] == 2015) {print a[5]}' file
123456
```